# Yapf (a formatter for python files) in Sublime Text 3 doesn't work. Access is denied

Tags: python-3.x, package, sublimetext3, formatter, yapf

When I press Ctrl + alt + F , It says :

> OSError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
>
> You may need to install YAPF and/or configure 'yapf_command' in PyYapf's Settings.

So I have already installed YAPF and configured in PyYapf's Settings  :

```
// full path and command to run yapf
"yapf_command":"C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32/Lib\\site-packages\\yapf",
```

What's wrong and with what? Why Yapf doesn't work. I've also installed a package of yapf.

Comment: generally you should have access under `"C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32/Lib\\site-packages\\yapf` if you are the same logged in user. You might want to check if you installed it as admin and have no access to it - simply browse to the directory and check its file/dir-permissions and if you can access it outside of sublime. maybe change them if you know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm that same user and I can access it outside of sublime. I mean just open it/

Comment: This error generally means that you're trying to run a directory instead of a program. Make sure you're also including the name of the program and not just the folder it's in.

Comment: Just to clarify that comment now that I'm not on mobile, while Access Denied can mean that you don't have permission to do a thing with a file, in the case of this error being generated by a build system on Windows, it usually means that you've accidentally entered the path to the place where the binary is in the `cmd` of your build system; in `cmd` it has to be the full path ***including the name of the program*** (i.e. you're telling it what to run, not where to find what you want to run).

Comment: There is no file named "yapf". Only folder. And even if I try to write full path with the name of some program, there are only ".py" files, so there is an error : 

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 Is Not a Valid Win32 Application


You may need to install YAPF and/or configure 'yapf_command' in PyYapf's Settings.

Comment: What does the documentation for the package you're using have to say about how to configure it?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts of problem:

1. *You may need to install YAPF*
2. *Configure 'yapf_command' in PyYapf's Settings.*

The first part can be solved by:

> pip install yapf

In second part of problem, you need to configure path to the **Yapf binary**. In Linux, binaries go to `/usr/bin/`. I'm not completly sure for Windows equivalent, but try <sup>[1](https://github.com/jason-kane/PyYapf/issues/35#issuecomment-367303297)</sup>:

```
{
  "yapf_command": "C:/Users/your_user_name/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/Scripts/yapf.exe"
}
```